# When calling destroy, record is not being removed from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a link_to meant to destroy a record:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete from DB', {:controller => 'foos', :action => 'destroy', :id => foo.id}, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-mini" %>
```

The destroy method in the controller:

```
  def destroy
    @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
    @foo.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Pressing the button doesn't delete the record, but if I open up rails console and call `.destroy` on an existing foo, it is removed from the DB.

Let me know if you see a mistake here.  Thanks.

Comment: Show your application log and config/routes.rb please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because you send `GET` request while you need to sent `DELETE` request in order to call `destroy` action. So, your link should look:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete from DB', foo, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-mini", :method => 'delete' %>
```