# ROR delete action not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action

I am beginner to ROR and I am following this tutorial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

So according to this tutorial I want to delete one post. But its not working it showing this error `The action 'destroy' could not be found for PostsController`

My post controller delete method looks like

```
 def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  logger.debug "***********************: #{@post.id}"
  @post.destroy

  redirect_to posts_path
end
```

In routes I mentioned resource `resources :posts` but still it is giving error for destroy action. Am I doing something wrong. Need Help.

Comment: How are you accessing your destroy action? A fairly common mistake is to do it as an HTTP GET rather than an HTTP DELETE. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467381/when-calling-destroy-record-is-not-being-removed-from-db/18467444#18467444

Comment: I see that `end` has a different indentation: Are you sure it's matching the `def`? Or is it closing the class definition?

Comment: Sorry for this poor question. All about `end`. I made it properly now and its working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mention the method as delete in your views?

If you are using Rails 4, you should do:

```
<%=link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

In Rails 3:

```
<%=link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post), method: :delete, confirm: 'Are you sure?' %>
```